# setTimeout function with document on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a trouble with my code. I want to do when i click on div that gets some class and after 1 second it removes that class. Here is example of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert('aaa');
  $(document).on("click", ".items-layout > div", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass('hover-effect');
    $this.off("click");
  }, function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var $self = $(this);
      $self.removeClass('hover-effect');
      alert('yolo');
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
alert('aaa');
$(document).on("click", ".items-layout > div", function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.addClass('hover-effect').off("click");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $this.removeClass('hover-effect');
            alert('yolo');
        }, 1000);
});
```

what was wrong:

you passed into `.on('click'` two functions. But you can pass only one (Second just ignored). So you need to move code from the second one into the first one. That's what I did

Comment: Any explanantion of the problem and why this fixes it?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sure

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <style>
            .hover-effect{
                background-color: #00733e;
            }
            .normal-effect{
                color: #000000;
                background-color: #ffffff;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="items-layout">
            <div>sample</div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                alert('aaa');
                $(document).on("click", ".items-layout > div", function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    console.log($this);
                    $this.addClass('hover-effect');
                    $this.off("click");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        var $self = $(this);
                        $self.removeClass('hover-effect');
                        $this.addClass('normal-effect');
                        alert('yolo');
                    }, 1000);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you ...

Comment: in your case `var $self = $(this);` will save incorrect context cause `this` is either window / undefined